# Can I use two or more gulpfile.js for one project?

Tags: node.js, gulp

I am using gulp and I want to decide two or more flow for certain situation like:

```
>gulp gulpfile.js
>gulp gulpfile2.js
```

How can I do this?

Comment: Why not just define different tasks in your gulpfile, then you can do things like `gulp build` or `gulp minify`.

Comment: yes,  I nearly forgot this way.  thanks~

Comment: But if I want such gulpfile.js be portable, what should i do?

Comment: What do you mean by portable?

Comment: I want to add some common gulp methods among every projects, and some specific gulp methods for one project. Then use .bat or .sh to chain them.